# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): result.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

does anyone know why my map function will not work? Im trying to get info from an API. Im getting "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): result.map is not a function." Thanks.

```
function getData(){            
  fetch("https://pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(
    result =>{
      result.map(country =>{

      })
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: `result` might not be an array.

Comment: `.map()` is an array prototype method. `result` probably isn't an array. Can you tell us what the value of `result` is?

Comment: [object Object]

Answer (score 3):

> result.map is not a function

This is telling you that .map does not exist on result. This may be because result is undefined or not an array.

[image]

edit: after trying out that endpoint you are using it looks like it is an object instead of an array.